# api request problem response 500 from backend

Tags: api, vue.js

All welcome, I ran into a problem in which at the time of passing id and body in the method it is received, it gives 500 errors. In swagger I have an infected method, it looks like this:
[swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaY5l.png)

Accordingly, in the body of the request, I pass all the parameters of the fields it needs (I drive them in strictly, just to check for operability):
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXiJV.png)

In response I get this:
[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FegTD.png)

If you try to do the same in the swagger, then the method works and a 200 response comes:
[swagger 200 response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrC41.png)

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to make the code asynchronous, I tried to pass fields in different ways, but nothing happens, the answer comes 500

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the id field inside the obj.

```
const form = {
      id: 790, 
      ...
}
```

You are passing too much params inside the callback (id, form).